# Am I the only one getting this error from emulator?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-emulator, flutter-dependencies

I've been experiencing such issue in my emulator.As you can see in the picture there is broken like display in the emulaotr sometimes this covers a small area or even a whole emulator display. What might be the solution?[android emuulator issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJWs5.jpg)

I tried to understand through the issue and even reinstalled vs-code and it's extensions.
I even checked by "flutter doctor" in the terminal but there was no any issue. I guess this is much which I can do and have been wasting enough time, so I'm searching for any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Tap on three dots [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S24N8.png)
   [image: 1]
2. Try different options
   [image: 2]
3. If not helped try update your graphic drivers.